# Sphinx query before and after a term

Tags: sphinx

Is it possible to set up a query in sphinx with a term that has to either also match a word before OR after?

- (TermBefore) (Term) (TermAfter)

so that both

- TermBefore Term
- Term TermAfter

would match but

- Term

does not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proximity search operator is pretty much designed for this

```
 "Term TermAfter"~2
```

http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#extended-syntax

---

Ah, I thought you meant 'TermAfter' to be actully be the same word, just that it can be before **or** after.

But if two different terms, possibly the easiest is just to do:

```
"TermBefore Term" | "Term TermAfter"
```

Just simple phrase operator, where either phrase must match.

---

Edit again:

If dont want the matchs adjecent use Strict order operator, rather htna phrase operator...

```
(TermBefore << Term) | (Term << TermAfter)
```

Comment: Thanks. If however I used the strict order since some terms are relevant only before and some after e.g. TermBefore << Term << TermAfter can I then set up some and/or for TermBefore/TermAfter to indicate a match?

Comment: Added a edit for the case where termbefore/after are different words.

Comment: Thanks. If however I used the strict order since some terms are relevant only before and some after e.g. TermBefore << Term << TermAfter can I then set up some and/or for TermBefore/TermAfter to indicate a match? (added duplicate comment so I could @ reply to the correct user)